# How to install launch agent on Mac os x 10.5 / 10.6

Tags: cocoa, macos, launchdagent

I have developed a launchAgent in cocoa. It works fine for me on dev environment, by placing the plist file in location /Library/LaunchAgents/.To distribute and install this on other laptops, I created the package using package maker tool. As part of installation process I want to change permission of the plist file and copy it to /Library/LaunchAgents location.
Could any one tell me how can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance for help....Any help will be appreciated ..!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PackageMaker, select the launchd plist, and in "Configuration" set the "Install" location to /Library/LaunchAgents/com.unicorn.omgponies.plist and the "Destination" to /. You probably don't want to enable relocation for a launchagent. Then go "Contents" and you can set the ownership and permissions there.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked for me...Can you also tell me how I can start the launchagent as soon it gets installed. Currently i need to start it manually.

Comment: @Unicorn: You need a postinstall script or action to invoke launchctl.

Comment: @Graham: I added an apple script with content <do shell script "launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/LaunchAgent.plist 2>&1;">, While installing the installation fails, saying post install script can not be executed.
In post-install section i had given path to script, Am I missing some thing here ?

Comment: @Unicorn: the postinstall script needs to be a shell script, not an apple script.

Comment: Oh yes, I figured it out, and it worked. But to add on my problems, I see two instances of app running, one as root and another as <user>. Did i do some thing wrong  here ?

Comment: You don't want to enable relocation for *anything*. It should be labeled “make installation randomly fail for no good reason”.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: relocation only tends to be a problem on developer systems (which admittedly makes it an egregious problem), in my experience.

Comment: @Unicorn - did you ever figure out your problem?  The reason that happened is that PackageMaker sudo's to root and any post-install actions automatically run as root, not the user.  I'm trying to figure out how to run the script as the user.

Comment: @TodK: if the launch agent is configured to only run in graphical sessions, then a root instance should never get run, unless root logs in to the console (which is not to be recommended).

Comment: @Graham - problem is that launchctl load <locationOfPlist> is run as root - so my plist has the assumed value of "Aqua" but runs as root. using the UserName field in the plist doesn't appear to give exactly the same rights as running launchctl load <locationOfPlist>.  Its an interesting problem to say the least.